# How to show only the last 3 values in input

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have an html input text , when the user try to type in, i want to show only the last 3 values and make the others as an password.

something like this : `*****456`

do you have any idea on how to achieve this using javascript or jquery ?

Comment: Did you try anything? If you post some code and tell us how far you've got, we can help.

Comment: Try googling for "onKeyUp" event in jquery:)

Answer (score 0):

Decided to take a stab at it. Not sure if I'd actually ever use this thought ...

```
function attachToInput(input) {

  // the actual characters
  var chars = [];

  // update the input with the hidden prefix version
  function updateInputValue() {
    var value   = chars.join("");
    var nHidden = Math.max(0, value.length - 3);
    var last3   = value.substr(nHidden);
    input.value = "*".repeat(nHidden) + last3;
  }

  // standard characters
  input.addEventListener("keypress", function (e) {
    var pos = input.selectionStart;
    var char = String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode);
    chars.splice(pos, 0, char);
    updateInputValue();
    e.preventDefault();
  });

  // backspace & delete
  input.addEventListener("keydown", function (e) {
    var pos = input.selectionStart;
    if (e.keyCode === 8) {
      chars.splice(pos - 1, 1);
      updateInputValue();
      e.preventDefault();
    }
    if (e.keyCode === 46) {
      chars.splice(pos, 1);
      updateInputValue();
      e.preventDefault();
    }
  });
}

$(function () {
  var input = document.getElementById("foo");
  attachToInput(input);
});
```